# PHP - unserialize is said null but contains an array

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, null

Why do this :

```
$myarray = array();
$_SESSION['myarray'] = serialize($myarray);

$myarray = unserialize($_SESSION['myarray']);
if ($myarray == null) {
    print_r($myarray);
    print("<br>no data");
    exit;
}
```

gives this as a result :

```
Array ( )
no data
```

How my var can contains an array and be tested TRUE to null ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) is responsible. An empty array and null both equal false. Because you use the `==` [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), type is not compared they are [considered equal](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). If you use the `===` comparison operator then an empty array is not equal to null as the if statement evaluates to false.

[Demo](https://eval.in/436400)

Comment: Thank you for these fine references

Answer (score 2):

Because of loose comparison that you are using ( `==` ), `$myarray == null` is the same as `$myarray == []`, loose comparison means that only values are compared and both these values are [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). To compare the type as well as the value use strict comparison with `===.`

[Type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I wrote?

Comment: @JohnConde, I'm sorry, I did not read the other answers while writing my own, but if it is such a problem I will delete my answer gladly.